# How to determine if item is last item in a set

Tags: python, loops, set

I have an arbitrary number of items in a set.

I want to do something different when I am on the last item of the set - is it possible to do so without having to find the length of the set and have a counter variable?

```
    for e in elements:
        if e is elements[-1]:
            json+='"%s"' % e 
            break
        json+='"%s",' % e
```

The above code will work for lists, but cannot work here as splices are not supported for sets.

Comment: Why not have the for loop be till elements[:-1] and then have your last element code under that?

Comment: last item in a `set()` or last item in a `list()`? Note that `set()` does not maintain insertion order.

Comment: Does it make sense to talk about "last element of a set" in the first place anyway?

Comment: @nikeros last or rather, *final*. It's actual "position" in the set is unimportant

Comment: In this specific case you could do `','.join(f'"{e}"' for e in elements)`

Comment: Is your code meant to be an illustration or do you actually want to join the elements of the set in a comma-separated string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving my comment above, you could do something like this:

```
s = {"A", "B", "C"}

i = iter(s)

element = next(i, None)

while element is not None:
    next_element = next(i, None)
    if next_element is None:
        # This is the last element
        print(element * 10)
    else:
        print(element)
    element = next_element
```

**OUTPUT**

```
B
A
CCCCCCCCCC
```

This is just an example how the *final* element could be applied a different transformation.

Comment: what if `s = {None}`?